# Hibernate doesn't encode UTF-8 when persisting objects to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm creating a Spring MVC web application. Objects persisted by Hibernate to MySQL database are encoded wrongly. The data is coming from a .jsp page form, and is passed to a controller method using POST method.

I already tried applying solutions proposed
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063372/hibernate-mysql-how-to-set-the-encoding-utf-8-for-database-and-tables)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758094/hibernate-encodes-wrong-while-persisting-objects-utf-8), but they don't seem to work.

This is the header I'm using on my JSP pages:

```
<%@page language="Java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This is the database configuration file I'm using in my application:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I also added a UTF-8 filter in my web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also tried to change collation of my database by running a command in MySQL Workbench (tried utf8, utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_polish_ci). I tried to change collation of only one table (the one containing UTF-8 string), too.

None of this works. UTF-8 characters are stored as "?". I know the error is occuring while persisting the object, because I print the object in my console before persisting, and UTF-8 is displayed correctly. So I assume the problem lies in the Hibernate configuration and/or MySQL database configuration.

I will provide additional configuration files, should that be necessary.

Here's the CREATE statement for the table involved:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Well we could do with knowing what your MySQL schema looks like, yes - what is the field type involved?

Comment: Field type in the database is VARCHAR(255). String on the Java side.

Comment: And are you able to store non-ASCII characters via MySQL workbench? If you do, are you able to retrieve them in your Java application? It's worth pinning down the problem as narrowly as possible.

Comment: Yes, I am able to store non-ASCII characters via MySQL workbench. I am able to retrieve them. The problem is occuring only when I persist them with Hibernate.

Comment: Right. In that case, I would suggest getting the web app part out of the picture entirely, and providing a short but complete example of a *console* app which just initializes Hibernate and then stores a value with a hard-coded string. All of this is trying to just reduce the problem surface area... and make it easier for others to reproduce the issue. (I don't have MySQL installed right now, but I can do so to experiment with if I know it won't be too hard to reproduce your issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the collation set properly on mysql? It can be checked using the following statements:

```
show variables like 'character%';
show variables like 'collation%';
```

To allow unicode to be used on mysql server:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
character-set-filesystem = utf8
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked. So the problem was in the general MySQL configuration settings rather than one schema. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.