# How To insert Gujarati in TextBox via Spring Hibernate in database?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to store gujarati in postgreSQL database using Java Spring Hibernate Project But it is storing something like this

> àª®à«àª¦à«àª¨àª¾ àªàª¯-àªªàª°àª¾àªàª¯ àªªàª¾àªàª³ àª àªµà«àª¯àªà«àª¤àª¿àª¨à«àª àª­à«àªà«àª

instead of

> મોદીના જય-પરાજય પાછળ આ વ્યક્તિનું ભેજું

In my database encoding is UTF-8, if I copy paste directly in `postgreSQL` it is storing properly but from `html` form in web application it is not storing properly.

Following is my `hibernate.hbm.cfg` file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        org.postgresql.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:postgresql://192.168.6.51:5432/JayHind?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pshiv</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    </property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>

    <mapping class="com.models.Role" />
    <mapping class="com.models.UserAttempts" />
    <mapping class="com.models.UserLogin" />
    <mapping class="com.models.UserRole" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Program" />
    <mapping class="com.models.NationalProgram" />
    <mapping class="com.models.StateProgram" />
    <mapping class="com.models.OtherProgram" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Video" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Contact" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Heading" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have also used

> % @ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" % >

in jsp pages this make gujarati display properly but in form submission there is still problem.

In model class

```
package com.models;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_heading_info", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")})
public class Heading {
private int id;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String message;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "message", nullable = false)
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
    /*byte ptext[] = null;
    try {
        ptext = message.getBytes("ISO_8859_1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
        this.message=value;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } */

}

}
```

I have also put filter in web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Expected Output

[image: expected op]

Current Output

[image: current op]

Comment: check the encoding, maybe?...

Comment: In my database encoding is UTF-8, if I copy paste directly in postgreSQL it is storing properly but from html form in web application it is not storing properly.

Comment: In the textbox I type Gujarati, but it stores garbage.

Comment: in hibernate also I used encoding but no luck

Comment: There are LAYERS of encoding and translating in the stack you are describing (browser, server, your application, hibernate, postgresql). You have to get it right in each of them. Unless you make an attempt to isolate the problem, you might as well be blindfolded. And there is no good way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to face this the last week, try this.
Use 'definitivo' has the textBox.getText() and convert to UTF-8

> byte ptext[] = definitivo.getBytes("ISO_8859_1");
>
> String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");

Comment: I am using spring hibernate.

Comment: Ok, so in the action where the form goes, you have to insert this code.

Comment: no this is not working for me i put this in my model pojo class setter but not working, it is converting string to '?????? ????'

Comment: Try to debug de code in the setters, see what is getting and what is converting to

Comment: After writing `System.out.println("controller "+heading.getMessage());` it gives me this in console - controller àª°àª¾àª¹à«?àª²-àª?àª?àª¿àª²à«?àª¶àª¨à«? àª¸àª?àª¯à«?àª?à«?àª¤ PC, àª®àª¾àª¯àª¾ àªªàª° àª¨àª°àª®, àª­àª¾àª?àªª àªªàª° àª?àª°àª®